# jTable how getting selected row data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-jtable

How can I get the data from the row I selected in jTable? Like for example I click on the first row and the data of the selected row goes to my inputbox.

Comment: Can you show your code so we have some context?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected elements by registering for the event 'selectionChanged' as give below,

```
$('#tableName').jtable({
        selecting: true,
        columnResizable: false,
        actions: {
        },
        fields: {
            KeyId: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                sorting: true
            },
            Description: {
                title: 'Description',
                create: false,
                list: false
            },
            StartDate: {
                title: 'Start Date'
            },
            EndDate: {
                title: 'End Date'
            },
            Status: {
                title: 'Status',
                list: false
            }
        },
        //Register to selectionChanged event to handle events
        selectionChanged: function () {
            var $selectedRows = $('#tableName').jtable('selectedRows');
            $selectedRows.each(function () {

                var record = $(this).data('record');
                var keyid = record.KeyId;
                var name = record.Name;

                alert(" KeyId:" + keyid + " Name:" + name);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get all table records data in json string:

```
/* Read each record and add it to json */
var $selectedRows = $('#your_table').jtable('selectedRows'),records = [];
$selectedRows.each(function () {
    var record = $(this).data('record');
    records.push(record);
});
var josn_data = JSON.stringify(records);
```